# Wordpress / Woocommerce Litespeed cache plugin not caching Homepage (frontpage)

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, litespeed

Experimenting with Litespeed cache plugin

Can't make home page to cache using the plugin.

Test domain is: https://ls.alexdev.gr/

I tried disabling the plugin and enabling caching only using .htaccess and it worked.

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
    CacheEnable public
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET|HEAD$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login|admin|register|post|cron
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !nocache
    RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:max-age=300]
</IfModule>
```

But with plugin I am always getting this header x-litespeed-cache-control: no-cache

When enabled LS Cache plugin generates different .htaccess block

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker MOBILE start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile|Android|Silk/|Kindle|BlackBerry|Opera\ Mini|Opera\ Mobi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+ismobile]
### marker MOBILE end ###

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is in some other plugin/theme.
I have disabled all plugins except Woocommerce & LS Cache
And enabled Storefront theme.

Everything worked.